# Como criptografar senha com Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, criptografia

Preciso criptografar senha utilizando Python, pelo que vi em exemplos em PHP, eles usam um "modulo" que criptografa a senha e que em tese não da para descriptografar, para validar a senha eles criptografa a senha que o usuário digitou e compara com a que esta criptografada no banco de dados.

Como fazer isso em Python? Pelo que consegui achar sobre/testei, toda vez que coloco para encriptar o resultado e sempre diferente, sendo assim como comparo? O que preciso aprender?

Exemplo fictício do que esta acontecendo comigo:

Primeira Tentativa:

```
msg = "1234"
encript(msg) >> adsadasfafsa
```

Segunda Tentativa:

```
msg = "1234"
encript(msg) >> weqwrewerwer
```

Concluindo toda vez que encripto o resultado é diferente, sendo assim não consigo comparar.

Answer (score 2):

Primeiramente, precisamos instalar o módulo do bcrypt, pois ele não vem por padrão. Para isso, basta digitar o seguinte comando no terminal:

```
sudo pip install bcrypt
```

Agora é só a gente utilizar o módulo. Vou postar um exemplo de uso.

```
import bcrypt

senha = '12345'
salt = bcrypt.gensalt(8)

print salt
$2a$08$K02Yy9Sn2mDReCeHwu3zse

hash = bcrypt.hashpw(senha, salt)

print hash
$2a$08$K02Yy9Sn2mDReCeHwu3zseMpikne058OpGqfMhKHhuDLIYrnvNT9G
```

Fonte: [blog pythoneiro - Como utilizar bcrypt em python?](http://pythoneiro.blogspot.com.br/2015/02/como-utilizar-bcrypt-em-python.html)

Comment: Você pode explicar um pouco melhor oque cada coisa faz? o que fica armazenado no salt, seria a chave?

Comment: Junior, basicamente o salt está armazenando a complexidade que voce utilizará na sua criptografia. Ao utilizar o comando HASHPW voce está encriptando sua senha com a complexidade selecionada (salt), voce pode passar esse valor direto para a função. que ficaria:   hash = bcrypt.hashpw(senha, bcrypt.gensalt(8))

Comment: Colocando isso num senário de Cadastro/Login, quando o usuário digita a sua senha na hora do cadastro, eu encripto ela com determinando SALT e salvo do db, e o SALT precisa ser salvo no caso; para quando o Usuário  for fazer login e eu comparar oque ele digitou com a senha que esta encriptada no db, correto?